# How to leave this object array without the at sign (@) in the keys - ES2006/ES2020

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to leave this object array without the at sign (@) in the keys to be in a static way, but in a dynamic way, because I will have cases that will be more given and with different key names;

Sometimes I may have @SIGLA, or NOT on the call;

how is it:

```js
const object = [
    {
      "@UF": "SP",
      "@SIGLA": "PJ",
      "@NUM_CONSELHO": "111",
      "@NOME": "JAMIL ANDRÉ",
      "@ID_PROFISSIONAL": "1221212"
    },
    {
      "@UF": "RJ",
      "@SIGLA": "CLT",
      "@NUM_CONSELHO": "2222",
      "@NOME": "POCARRONTAS",
      "@ID_PROFISSIONAL": "212121212"
    },]
```

how has to be:

```js
const object = [
    {
      "UF": "SP",
      "SIGLA": "PJ",
      "NUM_CONSELHO": "111",
      "NOME": "JAMIL ANDRÉ",
      "ID_PROFISSIONAL": "1221212"
    },
    {
      "UF": "RJ",
      "SIGLA": "CLT",
      "NUM_CONSELHO": "2222",
      "NOME": "POCARRONTAS",
      "ID_PROFISSIONAL": "212121212"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through the objects and remove the `@`:

```
let y = {};
for (key in x) {
    y[key.replace(/^@/,'')] = x[key];
}
x = y;
```

Doing it for the entire array:

```
for (let i=0; i<object.length; i++) {
    let y = {};
    for (key in object[i]) {
        y[key.replace(/^@/,'')] = object[i][key];
    }
    object[i] = y;
}
```

Comment: what would it be like to apply a map or filter?

Comment: You can `map` if you want to create a new array but if you simply want to remove the `@` instead of creating a new variable with the `@` removed then doing it in-place uses less RAM. A better option is to use the two argument version of `forEach`: `object.forEach(val,i)`. As for looping over the objects themselves you can use `map` with `Object.keys()` but that would be much more cumbersome and result in longer code than `for...in`

Answer (score 0):

you can use map method

```
const object = [{
    "@UF": "SP",
    "@SIGLA": "PJ",
    "@NUM_CONSELHO": "111",
    "@NOME": "JAMIL ANDRÉ",
    "@ID_PROFISSIONAL": "1221212"
  },
  {
    "@UF": "RJ",
    "@SIGLA": "CLT",
    "@NUM_CONSELHO": "2222",
    "@NOME": "POCARRONTAS",
    "@ID_PROFISSIONAL": "212121212"
  },
];
var newArray = object.map((i, k) => {
  var newObj={};
  for (let key in i) {
    var str = key.split('@');
    newObj[str[1]] = i[key];
  }
 return newObj;
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: yours is coming with a comma before the key

Comment: @CharlesLindo no it does not

Answer (score -1):

Below is another way for using `map`

```js
const object = [
    {
      "@UF": "SP",
      "@SIGLA": "PJ",
      "@NUM_CONSELHO": "111",
      "@NOME": "JAMIL ANDRÉ",
      "@ID_PROFISSIONAL": "1221212"
    },
    {
      "@UF": "RJ",
      "@SIGLA": "CLT",
      "@NUM_CONSELHO": "2222",
      "@NOME": "POCARRONTAS",
      "@ID_PROFISSIONAL": "212121212"
    },
];

const newArray = object.map(object => {
    const newObject = {};
    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(object)) {
        const newKey = key.replace('@', '');
        newObject[newKey] = val;
    }
    return newObject;
});
```

Comment: its understood better by the fact that you are using ES better. Vlw friend, but I can't take the merit out of the slebetman

Comment: @CharlesLindo That's okay. If my answer helped for you, I'm glad with that. Thank you. :)